# How to display a subfolder's contents when the primary URL is loaded, without redirecting to the subfolder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website `www.example.com`. When users load this website, I want them to see the contents of `www.example.com/foo/`, whilst staying on `www.example.com`. Additionally, I wish for `www.example.com/foo/` to return me a 404 message.

How is this possible with `.htaccess`?

Comment: I mean no offense here, and am genuinely curious: With a good rep of 7,000+, why are you asking a question that is considered off-topic on Stack Overflow? This question doesn't give much context or insight, and doesn't show what you tried, and the problem that was faced. I have had a look at several other questions you've posted, and they are all considered on-topic...

Comment: @MikeRockett Haha sorry to disappoint :) I just ask questions based on my current needs. I tried searching this up on the internet, and I couldn't find anything that matched what I wanted, so I created a question. After a bit of tweaking, I figured it out and posted a viable solution. Given I provided code in the format of an answer, I guess that quantifies as on-topic?

Comment: Not sure disappointed is the word to use. ;) In Q&A format, I'm not sure that it becomes on-topic, as the code isn't in the question. Nonetheless, it may help others who have the same problem, so I am sure it can remain as-is. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix after a bit of searching and fiddling. I've currently got this in the root of my website (in `public_html`, where `public_html/foo/` is the folder in question):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/$1 [L]
```